# PDF link reloads the page instead of downloading the PDF

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pdf, download

I'm using WordPress for a website and I am editting the theme manually.
I want to have a link that will prompt a download of a pdf document when clicked.

What happens currently is that when I click the link, it just reloads the homepage.

I'm using

```
< a href="/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2013.pdf">Application Form< /a>
```

inside my footer.php for the hyperlink.

you can view its behavior for yourself at

www.pepperdine-graphic.com

by clicking on the "Application Form" link in the footer.

Comment: In your "uploads" directory, do you have an .htaccess file that restricts access for expected images (gifs, jps etc). It's a common security restriction that if you access other types of file then it throws you out.

Comment: .htaccess files are hidden correct?  wouldn't happen to know how to view hidden files using coda 2?

Comment: Google it? http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/07/top-20-secrets-of-coda-2/ is a top link and has instructions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like file does not exist:

```
WEB_ROOT/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2013.pdf
```

And server has redirect to an index.php if file does not exist.
Just add file to proper folder or change link to point to proper file.

Comment: i got the link by right clicking on the file from my ftp client (coda 2) and then clicking "copy path" and pasting it into the href, so that is, in fact, where the file is located

Comment: replace with `/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2013.pdf` as `http://www.pepperdine-graphic.com/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2013.pdf` works for me

Comment: so that the link looks like  /WordPress/http://w ww.pepperdine-graphic.com/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2‌​013.pdf  ?

Comment: `<a href="/wp-content/uploads/files/application-spring-2013.pdf">Application Form</a>`